# Creating two square waves in assembly for the 6502

Tags: assembly, microprocessors, 6502

I am trying to generate two outputs: a 20Hz square wave and a 30Hz square wave in assembly using a 6502 micro controller instruction set. So far, I can output on 20Hz wave:

```
%uasm65,title="SQUARES"
    org 0200h
    lda #1d
    sta 0a200h
Main:
    ;jump to the subroutine Delay and do it
    jsr Delay
    lda 0a200h
    inc Count1
    lda Count1
    cmp #3d
    beq Reset1
    jmp Main

Reset1:
    lda #0d
    sta Count1
    lda 0a200h
    eor #00000001b
    sta 0a200h
    jmp Main

Reset2:
    jmp Main

Delay:
    ;Save registers on the stack.
    pha
    txa
    pha
    tya
    pha

;Change the number that is being loaded into the
; 'A' register in order to change the delay time.
    lda #01h

OutLoop:
    ldx #04h

InLoop1:
    ldy #0ffh

InLoop2:
    dey
    bne InLoop2

    dex
    bne InLoop1

    sec
    sbc #1d
    bne OutLoop

;Restore registers from the stack.
    pla
    tay
    pla
    tax
    pla

    rts

Count1:
    dbt 0d

Count2:
    dbt 0d

    end

%/uasm65
```

From my understanding, what I can do to accomplish this is to take a 60Hz square wave and use it to get a 30Hz and a 20Hz. How would output a 20Hz square wave to bit 5 of PortA and a 30Hz square wave to bit 6 of PortA without affecting the state of the other bits in the port? In other words, how do I get 20 and 30 from 60 here? Do I let the count check for 7 and increment count 2? any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just `eor` the appropriate bit, not sure what your problem is?

Comment: The issue is is getting two different frequency outputs without the two overriding the other (since the reset1 sets it back to zero).

Comment: That's why you have the lowest common multiple (60Hz). You make two counters, one from 20 and one from 30, and flip the appropriate bit when it hits zero. Sometimes you will flip both, but you can do that one after another.

Comment: Should have been 2 and 3 of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need 2 separate counters, one for each pin

```
Main:
    ;jump to the subroutine Delay and do it
    jsr Delay
    lda 0a200h      ; ?? what's this doing here?

    inc Count1   ; count1 is for the 20 Hz bit pin
    lda Count1
    cmp #3d       ; 60/20 = 3, so counter1 will have to reach 3
    bne Skip1     ; otherwise skip toggling
toggle_pin5:
    lda #0d       ; reload first Counter
    sta Count1
    lda 0a200h
    eor #00000001b
    sta 0a200h
skip1:

    inc Count2    ; count2 is for the 30 Hz bit pin
    lda Count2
    cmp #2d       ; 60/30 = 2, so counter2 will have to reach 2
    bne Skip2     ; you could also "bne Main" here
toggle_pin6:
    lda #0d       ; reload 2nd Counter
    sta Count2
    lda 0a200h
    eor #00000010b ; you will want to change this for the correct value to "set bit6 of PortA"
    sta 0a200h

skip2:
    jmp Main    

Reset1:     ; not needed anymore
Reset2:     ; not needed anymore

Delay: [ ... ]
```

Inside your loop, branching to Reset1 (or Reset2), and the jumping back to Main isn't such a good idea, you'd skip the 2nd check for the 2nd pin. Better just branch over the few instructions (as I did), or use a JSR/RET:

```
    cmp #3d
    bne SkipCall    ; counter value NOT reached, so skip "Reset"
    jsr Reset
SkipCall:
    <...>

Reset: 
    lda #0d
    sta Count1
    <...>
    ret
```

Comment: Very thorough.  :) Thanks. Yeah, I just did the lda to make sure the value after the delay was correctly loaded into memory and is kind of redundant.

Comment: Hmm, with only one register, it's inconvenient to only do one `sta 0a200h` with both changes.  It would be possible to do the two `EOR`s separately on a copy of what's on the port, then copy it that to `0a200h`.  Maybe you can use the `X` and `Y` regs for something?  Have one of them zeroed so you can `sty Count2` to zero it, instead of `lda #0d` / `sta`?

Comment: @user3050884: Oh, by counting down from 3 or 2, instead of up towards 3 or 2, you can save a lot of instructions: `dec Count1` / `bne Skip1`.  This leaves you free to keep the I/O port data in the accumulator, so you can just load it once, `EOR` it or not, then store it once.  (The load/store would happen every time, not just when toggles were actually needed, though.)  If you keep `X=2` and `Y=3`, then depending on the delay loop, you can keep the I/O port data in `A` permanently and never need to load it.

Comment: Turned that idea into an answer with a huge saving in code-size. :)

Answer (score 2):

According to my reading of [the instruction set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOS_Technology_6502#Assembly_language_instructions), this should work and be shorter than Tommylee's code.  (I used that as a starting point).

Counting towards zero is preferable in asm, if you use a decrement that sets the zero flag when the result reaches zero.  Then you don't need a separate compare.  This can get the code-size down to `0x1D` bytes (for my 2nd version).

I'm assuming that `dec` with a memory operand still sets flags according to the result.  I haven't looked at any 6502 docs other than wikipedia. :P  The code in the question uses `dey`/`bne`, so I assume that's correct and sets flags.

Assuming that optimizing for fewer instructions is better, you should try to cut down the delay loop a lot.  Maybe just nested loops of memory decrements with `bne` as the loop condition (so you loop 2^n times)?  Unless using memory costs more power?

```
Main:
    ldx  #3d         ; 60/20 = 3: toggle every 3 iterations
    ; stx  Count5    ; Count5 is for the 20 Hz bit wave on pin5
    ldy  #2d         ; 60/30 = 2: toggle every 2 iteration
    ; sty  Count6    ; Count6 is for the 30 Hz bit wave on pin6
    ; omit the stores: Count5 and Count6 are already initialized.

    ; lda  0a200h      ; start with the initial state of the I/O port
    lda  #1d          ; constant initial state

squarewave_loop:
    jsr  Delay
    ; lda  0a200h     ; or do this here, so Delay doesn't have to save/restore A

    dec  Count1    
    bne  skip1        ; toggle when it reaches zero
toggle_pin5:
    stx  Count5       ; reload first countdown counter
    eor  #00000001b
skip1:

    dec  Count2
    bne  skip2        ; toggle when it reaches zero
toggle_pin6:
    sty  Count6
    eor  #00000010b ; FIXME: which bit maps to bit6 of Port A?
skip2:

    sta  0a200h       ; always store, even if there was no state change
    jmp squarewave_loop

Delay: [ ... ]

Count1:
    dbt 3d
Count2:
    dbt 2d
```

---

#### Or, use `dey` / `dex` for count1/count2

Then we don't need any memory to store the counters, and I assume instructions with memory operands have a longer encoding

```
Main:
    ldx  #3d         ; 60/20 = 3: toggle every 3 iterations
    ldy  #2d         ; 60/30 = 2: toggle every 2 iteration

    ; lda  0a200h      ; start with the initial state of the I/O port
    lda  #1d          ; constant initial state

squarewave_loop:
    jsr  Delay
    ; lda  0a200h     ; or do this here, so Delay doesn't have to save/restore A

    dex
    bne  skip1
       ;toggle_pin5:     ; runs when 1st down-counter hits zero
    ldx  #3d             ; reload the countdown
    eor  #00000001b
skip1:

    dey
    bne  skip2
       ;toggle_pin6:     ; runs when 2nd down-counter hits zero
    ldy  #2d
    eor  #00000010b ; FIXME: which bit maps to bit6 of Port A?
skip2:

    sta  0a200h          ; always store, even if there was no state change
    jmp squarewave_loop

Delay: [ ... ]
```

This assembles on http://www.masswerk.at/6502/assembler.html, if I strip out the comments and remove the `:` character from the end of labels.  The total size, not counting the delay loop, is 0x1D bytes of code.

Comment: hey, always there when it comes to optimization :) 
I'm also a friend of counting from max_value downwards, the branch is easier to read, and with a single good comment, you've explained the whole loop thing.  But I didn't want to throw the OPs completely overboard, because his approach was (nearly) working already ;-)
This 2nd way would finally use X and Y, which are ( currently unnecessarily ) pushed and popped in the delay subroutine :-)

Comment: perhaps it would make sense to use 2 Constants for the 2 Counter Values (2 and 3), to remove the redundancy ("first" init with value, and then again reloading it on output toggle); then you can't forget changing one but not the other, if a modification is needed

Comment: @Tommylee2k: absolutely agreed on using symbolic constants.  I saw that maintainability issue while writing it, but I don't know the 6502 assembler syntax for defining symbolic constants that turn into immediates.  (like NASM `c1 equ 0x2`).

Comment: "Unless using memory costs more power?" My understanding is that the 6502 has a quirk where even if the instruction being executed isn't a memory access instruction, it will always perform a memory access cycle anyway (just repeating the last memory operation), so it should make no difference at all to power consumption (that said, like yourself I haven't done much with 6502s previoisly, do I could be getting this wrong...)